# "Restarting adb... Installation aborted." without any further details after abd sideload

Tags: side-loading

I'm trying to setup a bulk of tablets with a custom ROM (as a kind of kiosk mode tablets for my company). In short all I'm doing is deleting all kind of stuff from the tablet and then I'm installing just my self-made kiosk app as a launcher app. I've already accomplished that by doing it manually on a rooted tablet. However I need to that for a bulk of tablets so I want to create an `update.zip` which automates that and apply it to all tablets by `adb sideload update.zip`.

When I try to load a minimalistic `update.zip` which I created to just learn and play around with the `update.zip` archive format I always get the following error:

[image: error message]

The minimalistic `update.zip` which just creates a tiny text file in `\system\` to proof that the update really has been applied can be downloaded here: [update.zip](https://upload.puaschitz.at/file/b8izt137mx11yvi/update.zip)

What's wrong with my ZIP? All similar questions on this topic seem to be related to signing issues, but:

- i've signed my ZIP
- and all the other issues get errors like `invalid signature` but I don't get any error message at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OTA update packages must be signed with one of the keys expected by the system or the installation process will reject them.

You cannot just apply a zip to a stock ROM using the stock recovery, even if it is signed. It must be signed with the key used when building the ROM/recovery, which is only available to the device maker. If you want to apply an update you need to have a custom recovery at the very least which should allow you to bypass the signature verification.

> **[Release keys](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds.html#release-keys)**
>
> The Android tree includes test-keys under
> build/target/product/security. Building an Android OS image using make
> will sign all .apk files using the test-keys. Since the test-keys are
> publicly known, anybody can sign their own .apk files with the same
> keys, which may allow them to replace or hijack system apps built into
> your OS image. For this reason it is critical to sign any publicly
> released or deployed Android OS image with a special set of
> release-keys that only you have access to.
>
> **[Signatures and sideloading](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds.html#sign-ota-packages)**
>
> Before installing a package, recovery will verify that it is signed with one of the private keys matching the public keys stored in the recovery partition, just as it would for a package delivered over-the-air.

Comment: Well, creating a custom update zip wouldn't make things easier then, when I still need to apply a custom ROM first.